# Giving two inputs to as single model and concatenating them

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model that takes one image as input and it works fine. now I want to give one more transformed image with the same dimensions as the first one as input to the model. The model should learn from both images. The below code shows an error: "**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given". I want to know why I have to give two inputs in the init function as well.

```
 class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_dim, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = []
        self.bn2 = []
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        for i in range(nConv - 1):
            self.conv2.append(nn.Conv2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1))
            self.bn2.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel))

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(nChannel)
        self.UB1 = nn.UpsamplingBilinear2d(scale_factor=2)
        self.deconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(nChannel, nChannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.conv1(x1)
        x1 = F.relu(x1)
        x1 = self.bn1(x1)
        x1 = self.pool1(x1)
        for i in range(nConv - 1):
            x1 = self.conv2[i](x1)
            x1 = F.relu(x1)
            x1 = self.bn2[i](x1)
            if i == 0:
                x1 = self.pool2(x1)
        x1 = self.conv3(x1)
        # x = F.relu(x)
        x1 = self.bn3(x1)

        x1 = self.UB1(x1)
        x1 = self.deconv(x1)
        x1 = F.relu(x1)
        x1 = self.bn3(x1)

        x1 = self.UB1(x1)
        x1 = self.deconv(x1)
        x1 = F.relu(x1)
        x1 = self.bn3(x1)

    


        x2 = self.conv1(x2)
        x2 = F.relu(x2)
        x2 = self.bn1(x2)
        x2 = self.pool1(x2)
        for i in range(nConv - 1):
            x2 = self.conv2[i](x2)
            x2 = F.relu(x2)
            x2 = self.bn2[i](x2)
            if i == 0:
                x2 = self.pool2(x2)
        x2 = self.conv3(x2)
        # x = F.relu(x)
        x2 = self.bn3(x2)

        x2 = self.UB1(x2)
        x2 = self.deconv(x2)
        x2 = F.relu(x2)
        x2 = self.bn3(x2)

        x2 = self.UB1(x2)
        x2 = self.deconv(x2)
        x2 = F.relu(x2)
        x2 = self.bn3(x2)
    

        x = torch.cat(x1,x2)
        return x
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you instantiate and call your object as well as the complete error backtrace.

Comment: model = MyNet(data.size(1), data_gr.size(1)),  data and data_gr are my two images.  Backtrace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_SUDF.py", line 246, in <module>
    model = MyNet(data.size(1), data_gr.size(1))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: You need to initialize your model class before calling it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I am doing it like this : "output = model(data, data_gr)[0]"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mre] and the full backtrace of your error message.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that 2 input images have the same size, so no need to pass 2 values on model instantiating (`model = MyNet(input_dim)`).

But `forward` then requires 2 inputs in your case it looks ok

```py
# init passing only single value `input_dim`
model = MyNet(input_dim)
...
# pseudo code for training stage
for batch in data_loader:
    img1, img2 = batch
    output = model(img1, img2)
```